# wanderlust: size and position of displayed images?

Tags: images, wanderlust

Using wanderlust in emacs-25.1.x, how can I specify the display size and position in the message buffer of attached images that are shown inline?

I want to display smaller versions of the images, and I'd like to arrange them in a grid at the bottom of the message.

I can't find anything in the wanderlust docs about this.

Thank you in advance.

**More info added ...**

OK. Here's what I have been able to determine so far. Images are displayed using the code in semi/mime-image.el. Near the top of that file is a static-cond which is used to select different methods for displaying images. The one that is selected by default makes use of the standard emacs 'insert-image' function. Here is its doc string:

> (insert-image IMAGE &optional STRING AREA SLICE)
>
> Insert IMAGE into current buffer at point. IMAGE is displayed by
>   inserting STRING into the current buffer with a ‘display’ property
>   whose value is the image.  STRING defaults to a single space if you
>   omit it. AREA is where to display the image.  AREA nil or omitted
>   means display it in the text area, a value of ‘left-margin’ means
>   display it in the left marginal area, a value of ‘right-margin’ means
>   display it in the right marginal area. SLICE specifies slice of IMAGE
>   to insert.  SLICE nil or omitted means insert whole image.  SLICE is a
>   list (X Y WIDTH HEIGHT) specifying the X and Y positions and WIDTH and
>   HEIGHT of image area to insert.  A float value 0.0 - 1.0 means
>   relative to the width or height of the image; integer values are taken
>   as pixel values.

So, even if I change how 'insert-image' is called, it can't be used to resize the image ... only to reposition it and display slices (subsets) of it.

In order to resize these images, I am going to have to add code to redefine new versions the 'mime-image-create' and 'mime-image-insert' functions that normally get defined in semi/mime-image.el.

I'm still not sure how to best do this. Perhaps I can use imagemagick's 'display' program to rescale the image text.

I'm investigating this, and I will continue to report my findings.

Comment: It may be that `w3m` kicks in to help display in-line images, but I'd need to check that to be sure . . .

Comment: Concerning w3m: I haven't been able to get emacs-w3m to work under emacs-25. The latest emacs-w3m I could find is from 2005 or 2006, and it's incompatible with emacs-25. Therefore, I would assume that wl is not using w3m on my emacs-25.1 system.

Comment: ... but I'm wrong. :)  I got w3m working with emacs-25 by using the cvs version of emacs-w3m.

Comment: To be clear, these are not technically "inline images". They are MIME attachments which are displayed inline, in the wanderlust message buffer. wl seems to use mime-view within the semi package to display these attachments. However, I couldn't find any code within the semi package which seems to have anything to do with the size and position of the images that are displayed withn the message buffer.

Comment: I figured out more info, and I added it to my original question, above.

Comment: I see that you are already on the right track -- i.e., starting with `mime-display-image` (working backwards/forwards from that starting point) and figure out whether to incorporate ImageMagic to do your resizing.  In terms of grouping the images by 4 in a row or something like that, well, you'd need to invest some time creating a custom solution -- from what I see, images are displayed following the file name which are by default one underneath the next.

Comment: Just for anyone reading this later, emacs-w3m is maintained on github.com at emacs-w3m/emacs-w3m, it is updated up through 2020. I've submitted pull requests which have been accepted and the developer is very responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do all of this. The "image+" package can be used to perform resizing of images and other manipulation:

https://github.com/mhayashi1120/Emacs-imagex

It utilizes temp files and some Imagemagick facilities.

With the help of this package, I now have come up with a way to (1) resize images, and (2) arrange them in a grid at the bottom of the message.

I did this by overriding the 'mime-display-image' function in 'semi/mime-image.el', as follows ...

```
(defvar my-images-per-line 3
  "*Number of images per line.")
(defvar my-max-image-width (truncate (/ (window-pixel-width) (1+ my-images-per-line)))
  "*Maximum image width.")
(defvar my-max-image-height (truncate (/ (window-pixel-height) 3.5))
  "*Maximum image height.")

(defun my-mime-display-image (entity situation)
  (message "Decoding image...")
  (condition-case err
      (let ((format (cdr (assq 'image-format situation)))
            (nimages 0)
            image
            size
            image-w
            image-h
            w-factor
            h-factor
            resize-factor
            current-point
            end-point)
        (setq image (mime-image-create (mime-entity-content entity)
                                       format 'data))
        (if (null image)
            (message "Invalid glyph!")
          (save-excursion
            (save-restriction
              ;; Count the number of images that are already entered
              ;; into this buffer.
              (widen)
              (setq current-point (point-min))
              (setq end-point (point-max))
              (while (<= current-point end-point)
                (when (get-char-property current-point 'display)
                  (setq nimages (1+ nimages)))
                (setq current-point (1+ current-point))))
            (setq size (image-size image t))
            (setq image-w (car size))
            (setq image-h (cdr size))
            (setq w-factor (/ (float my-max-image-width) image-w))
            (setq h-factor (/ (float my-max-image-height) image-h))
            (setq resize-factor (min w-factor h-factor))
            ;; Enter a single newline if it's the first image to be entered.
            ;; Enter 3 newlines if we've already entered 'my-images-per-line'
            ;; images on the current line.
            (when (= (% nimages my-images-per-line) 0)
              (insert-char ?\n (if (< nimages 1) 1 3)))
            ;; Always precede each image with a few spaces.
            (insert-char ?\s 3)
            (setq current-point (point))
            (mime-image-insert image)
            ;; If resize-factor is not close to 1.00, use the image+
            ;; module to resize the image. It operates on the image
            ;; located at the current point.
            ;; For image+, see https://github.com/mhayashi1120/Emacs-imagex
            (when (> (abs (- resize-factor 1.00)) 0.05)
              (goto-char current-point)
              (imagex-sticky-mode 1)
              (imagex-sticky--zoom resize-factor))
            (message "Decoding image...done")
            )))
        (error nil err)))
(advice-add 'mime-display-image :override #'my-mime-display-image)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one idea using the built-in `image-dired` library and the external utility `convert` that is part of the ImageMagick suite.  Emacs does not need to be built with ImageMagick support for this idea to work, but `convert` and its dependencies must be on the computer.  I am only shrinking the image, not organizing the attachments in groups of four or anything fancy like that.

I have added support in `mime-display-image` for converting PDF full size to PNG thumbnails (first page only).

I found a `mime-preview-condition` in `mime-view.el` that conflicts with my new proposed condition, and I resolved the conflict by simply commenting it out.  In a nutshell, I don't want `mime-display-text/plain` to be triggered when dealing with a PDF.  If anyone sees a negative effect by commenting out those lines, please post a comment and let me know -- along with a suggested fix (if known).

NOTE:  I added the `-flatten` argument to `image-dired-cmd-create-thumbnail-options` (*in my own setup*) in order to make transparent PNG background white.  The user may choose to do the same.  In my use case, I create PDF with `pdflatex` from `TexLive` and PDF converted to PNG without `-flatten` do not show up well in a buffer with a dark background.

```lisp
(ctree-set-calist-strictly
  'mime-preview-condition
  '((type . application)
    (subtype . pdf)
    (body . visible)
    (body-presentation-method . mime-display-image)
    (image-format . pdf)))

;; Comment out the following lines in `mime-view.el':
;;    (ctree-set-calist-strictly
;;      'mime-preview-condition
;;      '((body . visible)
;;        (body-presentation-method . mime-display-text/plain)))

(defun mime-display-image (entity situation)
  (message "Decoding image ...")
  (condition-case err
    (let* ((format (cdr (assq 'image-format situation)))
           (image
             (unless (eq format 'pdf)
               (mime-image-create (mime-entity-content entity) format 'data))))
      (if (and (null image) (not (eq format 'pdf)))
          (message "Invalid glyph!")
        (save-excursion
          ;;; (insert-image image)
          (let* ((buffer (current-buffer))
                 (basename (mime-entity-filename entity))
                 ;;; `temporary-file-directory' `should` already have a forward
                 ;;;  trailing slash.  Use the `wl-temporary-file-directory'?
                 (tmp-dir
                   (concat
                     (file-name-as-directory temporary-file-directory)
                      "wanderlust/"))
                 (wl-extract-dir (concat tmp-dir "full-size/"))
                 (wl-thumbnails (concat tmp-dir "thumbnails/"))
                 (curr-file (concat wl-extract-dir basename))
                 (image-dired-dir wl-thumbnails)
                 (image-dired-thumb-width 200)
                 (image-dired-thumb-height 200))
            (when (or image (eq format 'pdf))
              ;;; `image-dired' will create the thumbnail directory.
              (unless (and (file-exists-p wl-extract-dir)
                           (file-directory-p wl-extract-dir))
                (make-directory wl-extract-dir 'parents))
              (mime-write-entity-content entity curr-file))
            (cond
              ((string-match (image-file-name-regexp) curr-file)
                (let ((thumb-name (image-dired-thumb-name curr-file)))
                  (if (and (not (file-exists-p thumb-name))
                           (not (= 0 (image-dired-create-thumb
                                        curr-file thumb-name))))
                      (message "Thumb could not be created for file %s"
                               curr-file)
                    (image-dired-insert-thumbnail
                      thumb-name curr-file buffer))))
              ((string-match "\\.\\(PDF\\)\\'" curr-file)
                (let* ((absolute-basename (file-name-sans-extension curr-file))
                       (png-filename (concat absolute-basename ".png"))
                       (pdf-first-page-filename (concat curr-file "[0]"))
                       (thumb-name (image-dired-thumb-name png-filename)))
                  (if (and (not (file-exists-p thumb-name))
                           (not (= 0 (image-dired-create-thumb
                                       pdf-first-page-filename thumb-name))))
                      (message "Thumb could not be created for file %s"
                               pdf-first-page-filename)
                    (image-dired-insert-thumbnail
                      thumb-name pdf-first-page-filename buffer))))
              (t
                ;;; catch-all / fall-back is the default behavior.
                (message "%s does not match `image-file-name-regexp'" curr-file)
                (insert-image image))))
          (insert "\n")
          (message "Decoding image ... done."))))
   (error nil err)))
```

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't paying attention, and I didn't notice this a few minutes ago when I entered my own solution, above. It looks like we're using similar methods, although I'm lazy and letting image+ do the Imagemagick and temp-file work :).